# Calling a servlet in chain of events

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, proxy

I have configured Apache httpd to work as a forward proxy server.

How can I add a servlet running on tomcat in the chain of events so that the servlet can access the requests and responses passing through the apache forward proxy server and modify them if required ( based on certain keywords) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module in apache can actually rewrite the url's.

**References:**

- [Mod Rewrite Examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/)

Comment: can you please elaborate how can I use mod_rewrite to solve my problem ? Thanks..

Comment: provided link which explains how to use it